# nginx as a reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy to a couple of web applications deployed within docker containers.  I can only expose port 80 from the docker server, and want to allow access to shipyard and rabbitMQ management web app.

Ideally, users could access the services via:
http[:]//10.10.10.1/shipyard/
http[:]//10.10.10.1/rabbitmq/

After quite a bit of research, trial and error this is my nginx config:

```
upstream rabbitmq {
    server 127.0.0.1:8888;
}

upstream shipyard {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.10.10.1;

    location /rabbitmq/ {
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection              'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass      http://rabbitmq/;
        proxy_redirect          default;
    }

    location /shipyard/ {
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header        Connection              'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass      $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass              http://shipyard/;
        proxy_redirect          default;
    }
}
```

When I access either path the apps I run into a couple of problems, which I believe maybe related:

- shipyard:
  Tries to load files from http[:]//10.10.10.1/api/containers, when it should be http[:]//10.10.10.1/shipyard/api/containers
- rabbitmq:
  Everything appears to work, until the server attempts to make a restful call:
  +++ PUT: http[:]//10.10.10.1/rabbitmq/api/queues///test2
  The server response with 405 (Not Allowed).  At first I thought the /// was the problem, that is how the rabbitMQ management application works.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question - did you manage to find final solution?
I am trying to resolve similar problem. I need to for "/" to jump to first container and for "/something" to another container and I am still failing on how to do this...

Comment: I did not.  It was easier to implement in Apache.

Comment: Well, I managed to find a solution finally. I adjusted nginx go template to get it working.